# How to rote bar-charts lable in react apex chart?

Tags: reactjs, charts, bar-chart, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

I am using the react-apex-chart library for the bar char representation in my project, I want the bar column's label value (like- 1500, 1700) to be rendered parallel to the bar, in case of horizontal view one column value overlaps with another column [image]

can someone help me to do the bar label (values) vertical (+90 deg)

Answer (score 1):

Change **orientation** of **dataLabels** in **plotOptions**
https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/bar/

```
plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        orientation: "vertical",
      },
    },
  },
```